# calculate count by month and year

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am trying to calculate how many people are on a waiting list or still on the waiting list at the end of the month. Ex. If 5 people are waiting in Jan and then in Feb 3 people get added to the list and one person in Feb gets off the list then at the end of Feb my count should be 7. I do have people on the list for over 365 days. So I need month and year.

My dates are in mm/dd/yyy . variables are dtlist(date went on list), dtofflist (date they went off list).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to include what RDBMS you're using (SQL Server, Oracle, etc.).  Also provide the table definition(s) and sample data in the form of actual `INSERT` statements and the desired results.

Comment: So sorry. I am using SQL server Management Studio. I do have individual IDKEY for each person that has been put on the waiting list. Thank you for any assistance.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? (2012, 2014, 2016, 2017)?

Comment: I am using 2017.

Comment: If you could share the schema of tables included in your query, it would be really helpful.

Comment: If `dtOffList` allows `NULL` values, you can just run something simple like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list WHERE dtOffList IS NULL`. But I'm wondering if you need to be able to view this data historically, like, "how many people were waiting on the list at the end of June 2017?" Otherwise I can't tell why the month/year matters. Do you need to know how long they have been waiting?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include any sample data in your question, so I made some up.  You would need to test my solution against your actual data to determine if it will work for you.

My solution uses a couple of common table expressions and a window function in the final select.  I commented various parts of the code in an attempt to explain what that section was doing.  My sample data also has some comments to document what the `TotalOnList` would be after that row was taken into consideration.

```
--Demo setup
set nocount on 
Declare @WaitingList table
(
   IdKey integer not null,
   dtlist    date not null, 
   dtofflist date

);

insert into @WaitingList (IdKey, dtlist, dtofflist)
values

--                                                  TotalOnList
(1,'2018-01-01', null),         --added in January      1
(1,'2018-01-02', null),         --added in January      2
(1,'2018-01-02', null),         --added in January      3
(1,'2018-01-02', null),         --added in January      4
(1,'2018-01-02', null),         --added in January      5

(1,'2018-02-01', null),         --added in February     6
(1,'2018-02-01', null),         --added in February     7
(1,'2018-02-01', null),         --added in February     8
(1,'2018-01-01', '2018-02-01'), --Left in Febuary       7

(1,'2018-02-01', '2018-03-01'), --Left in March         6

(1,'2018-04-01', null)  --added in April                7
;

--The solution

--union Dates for DateOnList and DateOffList
--Increment/Decrement accordingly
;WITH FormattedYearAndMonth
AS (
    --Increment for rows where dtofflist is null - these are people added to the list
    SELECT convert(VARCHAR(4), year(dtlist)) + right(replicate('0', 2) + convert(VARCHAR(2), month(dtlist)), 2) AS YearAndMonth
        ,+ 1 AS IncrementDecrement
    FROM @WaitingList
    WHERE dtofflist IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    --Decrement for rows where dtofflist is NOT null - these are people deleted from the list
    SELECT convert(VARCHAR(4), year(dtofflist)) + right(replicate('0', 2) + convert(VARCHAR(2), month(dtofflist)), 2) AS YearAndMonth
        ,- 1 AS IncrementDecrement
    FROM @WaitingList
    WHERE dtofflist IS NOT NULL
    )
    --Aggregate NetIncreaseForMonth
    ,AggregateForYearAndMonth
AS (
    SELECT YearAndMonth
        ,sum(IncrementDecrement) AS NetIncreaseForMonth
    FROM FormattedYearAndMonth
    GROUP BY YearAndMonth
    )
SELECT YearAndMonth
    ,Sum(NetIncreaseForMonth) OVER (
        ORDER BY YearAndMonth
        ) AS TotalOnList
FROM AggregateForYearAndMonth
ORDER BY YearAndMonth
```

---

```
| YearAndMonth | TotalOnList |
|--------------|-------------|
| 201801       | 5           |
| 201802       | 7           |
| 201803       | 6           |
| 201804       | 7           |
```